# How to rename a column in a pandas dataframe using a prompted user input without reformatting the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I wish to make a code that will concatenate all files in a folder, allow the user to rename certain columns, then further work up those tables. Generally this all works fine except that the outputs, when I rename with user input, is reformatted in a way I do not desire in that we retain "" and add a row break, apparently. This is python 2.7. code:

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd   
import sys
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.filename = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(initialdir = "/",title = "Select directory") 

path = root.filename
os.path.normpath
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "test*.txt"))     

full_df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, sep=r'\t') for f in all_files), ignore_index=True)
material1 = str(raw_input("Please input first key "))
material2 = str(raw_input("Please input second key "))
material3 = str(raw_input("Please input third key "))
material4 = str(raw_input("Please input fourth key "))

full_df2 = full_df.rename(columns={"W":material1})
print full_df2
full_df.to_csv(r'full_df.txt')
full_df2.to_csv(r'full_df2.txt')
```

Currently the column names I would seek to replace are W/X/Y/Z (input simply as placeholders in my text files for testing this). Ideally I could replace those with the user inputs, but currently that causes the header section to be reformatted. The output csvs currently are:

full_df (desired formatting) :

```
,sample ID,W,X,Y,Z
0,1,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25
1,1,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25
.
.
.
```

full_df2 (W is replaced, but the formatting has been changed) :

```
,sample ID,"a
",X,Y,Z
0,1,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25
1,1,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25
.
.
.
```

command line output for full_df2 is

```
    sample ID   a\r     X     Y     Z
0           1  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25
```

desired output would instead be

```
    sample ID   a     X     Y     Z
0           1  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25
```

and text files as

```
,sample ID,a,X,Y,Z
0,1,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25
1,1,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25
.
.
.
```

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: `columns={"W":material1.strip()}`. This is an example showing that using user input is dangerous. You would need to check `material1` before passing it to rename.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, in a future iteration I would want the keys to be pulled from the data directly. I believe in that case I would need to set up the logic similarly, ie with .strip() .